# Clouds on a tidally-locked planet

Tags: planets, weather, tidally-locked, clouds

I have an ocean world in my science-fiction universe which is tidally-locked to its star. The planet is a tidally-detached moon from one the gas giants in the outer system, and orbits a red dwarf star. It receives about 66% of the solar radiation that earth receives from the sun, and its gravity is 26% that of earth. The atmospheric pressure is 0.8 bars, and the air is almost entirely composed of abiotic oxygen, (with a small percentage of carbon dioxide).

The planet is entirely covered in ocean, with no exposed landmasses.

How would the tidally-locked nature of this planet affect its cloud formations? What would they look like?

Comment: There are [four other questions on this Stack about tidally-locked weather](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+[tidally-locked]+[weather]) and [five questions about tidally-locked climate](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+%5Btidally-locked%5D+%5Bclimate%5D). Spot checking a couple of them, you've a good chance of having asked a duplicate question. Did you do your research on this Stack before asking the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are essentially three possibilities which are impossible to distinguish with the level of detail that you have provided:

1. Venus-like. Circulation in cloud-forming layers is dominated by global superrotation, resulting in bands of clouds bent into chevrons centered on the equator and pointing eastward.
2. Double cyclone. The northern and southern hemispheres each support a permanent cyclone roughly centered on the substellar meridian, producing the spiral cloud patterns that are familiar from hurricanes and typhoons on Earth. Airflow at the equator is mostly eastward, but switches westward near the western terminator where the divergence is fed by air flowing over the poles from the darkside.
3. Single cyclone. A single cyclone, rotating in either direction, roughly centered on the substellar point, dominates circulation in both hemispheres on the dayside. Away from the cyclone and near the terminator, circulation is still dominated by air flowing to the darkside along the equator and back to the dayside over the poles.